# Why would Preview save just my annotations?

Tags: preview, screen-capture

I was using Preview to annotate a screenshot for a question on Apple.StackExchange.com and I saved it. For some reason, it only saved my annotation. I must've spaced out and accidentally pressed something, but what might that something be?
[image]

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you using, and what version of Preview?

Comment: I was using Snow Leopard at the time. I'm on Lion now, no repro, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select All and Delete would have been done the trick :)  You've deleted the screenshot (which was in the background) but kept the annotations.

Comment: This happened again! It's not that...

Comment: Do you recall this time what happened?

Comment: I annotated a screenshot and then I tried to save it. Save thing happened.

Comment: Does it happen every time you try it or just at random?

Comment: It seems to be at random. I think it's happened when I did a combination of crop and annotate, but I don't think it was consistent.